# Get post ID from a PHP class

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, class

I'm writing a plugin that will update the wordpress database with a click of a hyperlink (jQuery).  The way I've learned to do this has me updating the database from a PHP class.

I'm able to capture and update my table with user_id using:

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$user_id = $current_user->ID;
```

I'm able to capture and update my table with blog_id using:

```
global $blog_id;
```

However, I'm not able to capture and update my table with post_id.  I've tried:

```
global $wp_query;
$post = $wp_query->post;
$post_id = $post->ID;
```

That doesn't work - $post_id returns 0.  In fact, at this point in this class, is_single is even returning FALSE.  I'm stuck and would really appreciate some help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The object property `$post` does not exist unless you are in **The Loop** (ahh, to be a WordPress user). Instead, use the object property `$posts`.

Reference: [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Properties)

Comment: I appreciate the reply.  Could you please be more specific?  I'm still at a loss.  Are you just saying to replace $post = $wp_query->post; with $post = $wp_query->posts;? That doesn't work, so I'm assuming I'm missing a step.

Comment: Here is how it was solved:  global $query_string;
                $posts = get_posts($query_string);
                foreach ($posts as $post) {
                    $post_id = $post->ID;
                }

Comment: Unfortunately, it appears I'm still struggling here.  The solution above worked, but only because I only had one post in that particular test blog.  I welcome any guidance on your initial direction.  Thanks!

Comment: I've determined that even $query_string is returning as empty from within the class. (in case this helps diagnose)

Comment: Could it possible be due to the fact that my class resides in my theme root's functions.php file?  Should I move it to another file, and include it from the footer?  Would that work?

Comment: var_dump($wp_query->posts); If you have posts in there, use them for your plugin's purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You must use `$posts` instead of `$post`

Comment: I appreciate the reply. Could you please be more specific? I'm still at a loss. Are you just saying to replace $post = $wp_query->post; with $post = $wp_query->posts;? That doesn't work, so I'm assuming I'm missing a step.